# Migration from 2factor otp to firebase in php laravel website

Tags: php, laravel, firebase, one-time-password, migrating

I want to migrate 2factor authentication to firebase authentication by email and phone number. I have website in laravel php with godaddy hosting. 400+ users already registered. I want to sync my database to firebase.